# PowerShell syntax error in SQL Agent Job calling psftp.exe

Tags: syntax-error, sql-server-2012, powershell-2.0, sftp, sql-agent-job

I apologize if cross-posting is verboten but I was getting no traction at ServerFault.com and thought I'd try here.Errors suggest this is a script syntax issue.

I have a simple PowerShell script that runs fine from the console (PSVersion 2.0).

```
$psftpPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\psftp.exe"
$sftpHost = "foo.baa.com"
$userName = "myusername"
$userPassword = "mypassword"
$todate =   Get-Date -format yyMMdd;
$fromdate   = (get-date).AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyMMdd")
$filename =  "RawData_Extract_$($fromdate)_$($todate).zip"
$cmd = @("lcd D:\Healthstream", "get $($filename)", "bye")
$cmd | & $psftpPath -pw $userPassword "$userName@$sftpHost"
```

I want to schedule it as a SQL Server Scheduled Job. When I set the "Type:" of job to PowerShell it fails with a Syntax Error on (or around) the $cmd line (line 9). I have tried running the "Job Owner" as me to eliminate key chain issues with the  "Run as: SQL Server Agent Service Account".

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So the work around is to call the script with "PowerShell D:\MyScript.ps1". Not ideal as this is an exception to our standard but it works. I would still like insight to why SQL Server Agent Jobs handle PowerShell code differently from the PowerShell Console...